# Why am I missing data when I receive packets over UDP?

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I'm trying to receive data over a UDP connection from another app running locally but I don't seem to be receiving all the data that is being sent. I believe it's because I'm receiving the data in a while loop which sometimes doesn't run quickly enough to receive all the data but I'm not sure of an alternative I can use to constantly receive data. I should be receiving a sine wave but I'm actually receiving what is shown in the figure.

```
import socket
import struct
import time
import numpy as np
import sys

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 2000

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

data_fifo = []

def receive_data():
    while True:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1472) # buffer size is 1472 bytes
        temp = struct.unpack('368f', data)
        data_fifo.extend(temp)
```

[image: received data]

Comment: what if you appended to your list giving you a list of lists inside the loop, then once you were done getting data unpacking it into you list of observations? just a shot in the dark not a solution. In fact, you could also take out the unpack and do that post receive I suppose.

Comment: Thanks @JonSG . I'm plotting this graph live in another thread so there isn't really an 'end' to the process It only ends when the user does Ctrl+C.

Comment: I think I agree w/ what @JonSG is suggesting, which (to my mind) sounds like a buffer. UDP already implements buffering at the OS level ([see here for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52795025/udp-buffers-where-are-they-whats-guaranteed)), but it might not hurt to roll your own in this case.

Comment: Perhaps you can push the raw data in this thread and process/unpack it in the other?

Comment: Increase the socket receive buffer as much as possible, and the socket send buffer in the sender if you can.

Comment: If you're going to use UDP, then you have to expect that sometimes UDP packets will get dropped; that's just how UDP is.  You can reduce the likelihood of packets getting dropped by increasing your receive-buffer size, reducing the amount of time your thread spends outside of recv(), etc, but you can never get it to zero.  You might consider switching over to TCP instead, if that is a problem.